# PropertyConfigurator.configure() method in log4j1.x is causing problem in magration to log4j2.X

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

we are migrating from log4j 1.x to log4j2.x. during migration we are facing an issue with PropertyConfigurator.configure() method is not available in log4j2.x.
what will be the alternative way to replace the PropertyCOnfigurator.configure the method to keep my existing logging framework working and implement the 2x jars.

Comment: _"is not available in log4j2.x"_: it is not available in `log4j-core`, but it is available in the compatibility library `log4j-1.2-api`.

Comment: as per the log4j migration guide there is a limitation for the compatibility library   #### 
They must not configure by calling the Log4j 1.x classes DOMConfigurator or PropertyConfigurator.  [link] https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html

Comment: Yep, that part of the documentation is outdated.

Comment: post copying the file and using PropertyConfigurator.configure(prop). it's creating the log file but does not write any logs.